# Run on Schedule not an option in Azure Web Jobs anymore?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I am using this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/getting-started-with-building-azure-webjobs-for-your-office365-sites  approach to create a web job and I am not able to see below screen. Is ‘Run on Schedule’ not an option anymore? 
 [image]

Below is the screen I am getting:

[image]

The web job works perfectly on demand but what I really need is to schedule. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a settings.job file to your WebJob. This can include a CHRON expression that specifies when the job should run. The appropriate docs are [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#user-content-scheduling-a-triggered-webjob).

Alternatively, you can use a TimerTriggerAttribute. This is a WebJobs SDK Extension. Docs and examples for doing so are [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). Note that if you use TimerTrigger, you'll need to make sure your WebJob is deployed as continuous. The TimerTrigger will wake up and call the designated methods based on the schedule that you provide.